# PHP how to change/add image title

Tags: php, javascript, html, image, image-gallery

I am new to php and I've downloaded a free source code for image gallery. It has admin account and you can upload image on it. Now when I upload image it generates random image title like numbers '4849404'. I want it to assign a specific title per image. How can I do that? I think here is the line for the image title if I'm not mistaken:

```
$RandomNumber   = rand(0, 9999999999); // We need same random name for both files.

// some information about image we need later.
$ImageName      = strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name']);
$ImageSize      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['size']; 
$TempSrc        = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'];
$ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type'];
$process        = true;



//Validate file + create image from uploaded file.
switch(strtolower($ImageType))
{
    case 'image/png':
        $CreatedImage = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
        break;      
    case 'image/gif':
        $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    default:
        die('Unsupported File!'); //output error
}

//get Image Size
list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);

//get file extension, this will be added after random name
$ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
$ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
$BigImageMaxWidth       = $CurWidth;
$BigImageMaxHeight      = $CurHeight;

//Set the Destination Image path with Random Name
$thumb_DestRandImageName    = $Thumb.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt; //Thumb name
$DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt; //Name for Big Image

//Resize image to our Specified Size by calling our resizeImage function.
if(resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxWidth,$BigImageMaxHeight,$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage))
{
    //Create Thumbnail for the Image
    resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbMaxWidth,$ThumbMaxHeight,$thumb_DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage);

    //respond with our images
    echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><td align="center"><img src="gallery/'.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt.'" alt="Resized Image"></td></tr></table>';

}else{
    die('Resize Error'); //output error
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like it only sets the thumbnail image to a random number? Is that what you wanted to change

Comment: Yes, I want to change the random number to a specific title. or just get the file name of the image that is upload. how can I do taht?

Comment: I've figured it out. I change the $RandomNumber to $ImageName. It works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is adding a random number for the title on the following lines:

```
$DestRandImageName = $DestinationDirectory.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;
```

and

```
$DestRandImageName = $DestinationDirectory.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;
```

Were it says $RandomNumber you could add the ability to set a name here e.g. put the above code into a method and pass through a variable that sets the name or you could retrieve the existing image name from the following variable:

```
$ImageName
```

Comment: I've figured it out. I changed the $RandomNumber to $ImageName. It works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you've posted seems to be creating and naming *thumbnails*, as we can notice from the comments and variable names:

```
//Set the Destination Image path with Random Name
$thumb_DestRandImageName    = $Thumb.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt; //Thumb name
```

and confirmed from its usage a few lines below in:

```
//Create Thumbnail for the Image
resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbMaxWidth,$ThumbMaxHeight,$thumb_DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage);
```

Read about the contents of [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) array - `name`, `type`, `size`, `tmp_name` and `error` to understand the details available. E.g. in the above code snippet,

```
$ImageName      = strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name']);
```

gets the original file name in lower case (because of [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)) which we can use as we see fit e.g. using it as such, or after adding some random string for the primary name. Also, as you might have noticed, file extension will also have to be managed separately.

Finally, if you are looking to rename the *originally uploaded files*, which is possibly using [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), dig around the code and test in similar fashion.

Comment: I've figured it out. I change the $RandomNumber to $ImageName. It works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

$thumb_DestRandImageName    = $Thumb.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt; //Thumb name
$DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;

this line is where you can add specific title.
$RandomNumber="title";